# Want to change Label inside div with ID using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just would like to change the contents of label which is inside a div,

```js
$('#ma').find("label[id=baa]").val("1");
```

```html
<div id="ma">
  <label id="baa">foaie</label>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: $('#ma').find("#baa").html("1");

Comment: seen as id's are meant to be unique -> `$("#baa").text("1");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you should use `html("your text")`

```js
$(function(){
  $('#ma').find("label[id=baa]").html("1");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ma">
<label id="baa">foaie</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note:  If the data is not HTML specific `.text()` might be better..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selector, please see the changes inline

```js
$(function(){
  $('#ma').find("label#baa").text("1");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ma">
<label id="baa">foaie</label>
</div>
```